# How to add several tasks to be done in a separate thread in Python?

Tags: python, qt, python-3.x, pyqt

I need to do some database retrieval and some GUI updating after that. How to align several tasks that have to be done one after another in a separate from the main thread? Is it ok then to update GUI from that second thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GUI must be updated by using signals/slots when you are outside the main thread

The general approach goes like this

```
class Worker(QObject):
    #declare as many signals you wish
    signalForUpdatingGUI1 = pyqtSignal(typeofdata)
    signalForUpdatingGUI2 = pyqtSignal() ...etc

    ...
    def performTask():
        #do your job here and after that emit the appropriate signal that will be handled by the main thread
        result = 'maybe the task needs to pass some data'
        signalForUpdatingGUI1.emit(result)
        #continue your job if neccessary
```

Then supposing that you have somewhere a main class where the GUI resides (e.g a MainWindow class) do the following

```
class MainWindow...
    def __init__ ...
        ...
        self.worker = Worker()
        self.workerThread = QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.workerThread)
        self.workerThread.started.connect(self.worker.performTask)
        self.workerThread.finished.connect(self.taskDone)
        #Connect the worker signals with methods for updating gui in the main thread
        self.worker.signalForUpdatingGUI.connect(self.updateGUI)
```

Start this thread from somewhere in the main thread

```
    def startJob():
        self.workerThread.start()
```

Whenever the thread has info for the GUI the connected methods will be executed

```
    def updateGUI(data):
        #manipulate widgets.  Use the passed data if neccessary
```

And finally don't forget ot quit the thread when workerThread.finished signal is emmited

```
    def taskDone():
        self.workerThread.quit()
        #Anyting else that needs to be done after finishing the job
        #Or even maybe start the thread again for something new
```

These are the basics. After doing these you can improvise as much as you want
For example you are free to define as many methods you want in the worker class and call them before starting the thread.(This might be helpful for passing data to the class so that it can operate on them when performTask is called)

Comment: As long as the `worker` object lives in the `workerThread`, it's never going to finish; it will just continue running the event loop until you manually quit the thread.

Comment: what about if there is no signal for the task? For example i want to walk DB and then populate QListWidget with the info in the DB. There is no signal for the insertion and the insertion must start after DB task is over

Comment: For stuff like that instead of using QListWidget, you'd better use QListView and implement the underlying model. There are a lot of guides for this. You can start from here http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/model-view-programming.html . It's for C++, but the same applies to python.